# Extract string between phrase and square brackets [ ... ]

Tags: r, stringr, rselenium

In a personal webscraping project I'm doing using Rselenium, I have parse a large chunk of HTML text. I now need to extract the information contained in "data: [ ... ]" and put it into a list where I can further take each component individually. How I got this is with the code:

```
remDr$findElement("xpath","/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/dl/dd[3]/a")$clickElement()
textprog<-remDr$findElement("xpath","/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/script")$getElementAttribute('outerHTML')[[1]]
doc<-htmlParse(textprog)
```

and doc gives the following output:
[image]

I need to get the numbers contained in "data: [ 3, 9, 73, 81, 0, 95, 9, 67, 96, ]" into a list where I can extract each value separately to append them onto another value as these are the decimals for the overall value I'm trying to get.
I'm not very confident with string extracting and haven't made much progress with this using other posts on stackoverflow.

Comment: The data is a JSON format.  There are several packages available.  Take a look the "jsonlite" for example.  You will have to remove the text before the first [. Perform a search here a stack overflow on how to handle this  data and then ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(stringr)

my_String <- "data: [ 3, 9, 73, 81, 0, 95, 9, 67, 96, ]"
numbers <- stringr::str_extract_all(my_String, "\\d{1,2}\\,")[[1]]
numbers <- stringr::str_replace_all(numbers, "\\,", "")
numbers <- as.numeric(numbers)

[1]  3  9 73 81  0 95  9 67 96
```